# How to measure memory without copy-on-write pages?

Tags: linux, memory

How can one measure total RSS memory occupied by a set of (forked) processes, without double-counting shared and copy-on-write pages?

Comment: Very interesting question, +1 - it should be possible by a deeper analyze of the `/proc/*/map` files, despite I never found a tool which could do that. The main problem is with it that the data structures to follow are much more complex as they seems. If you don't get a nice answer here maybe you could try unix SE, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up writing my own utility for this: https://gist.github.com/Eugeny/04ccfe8accf4bc74b0ca

I ran it against `init` (pid 1) for testing and the total reported roughly equals the physical ram usage (as per htop), so I guess it's somewhat correct.

Example use:

```
~ » pstree -ap 15897
zsh,15897
  └─sudo,9783 make rundev
      └─make,9784 rundev
          └─sh,9785 -c cd ajenti-panel && ./ajenti-panel -v --autologin --plugins ../plugins --dev
              └─python ./ajenti,9786
                  ├─./ajenti-panel ,9834                              
                  ├─./ajenti-panel ,9795                     
                  └─{python ./ajenti},9796

~ » sudo ./memuse.py 15897
PID                 Commandline                          Frames (+unique)           VMEM
 - 15897            (/usr/bin/zsh                  ):      1776  +1776           7104 KB
  -  9783           (sudo make rundev              ):       608  +408            2432 KB
   -  9784          (make rundev                   ):       261  +98             1044 KB
    -  9785         (/bin/sh -c cd ajenti-panel && ):       166  +48              664 KB
     -  9786        (python ./ajenti-panel -v --aut):      9279  +8977          37116 KB
      -  9795       (./ajenti-panel worker [restric):      7637  +1334          30548 KB
      -  9834       (./ajenti-panel worker [session):      8972  +2639          35888 KB
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL:                                                    15280                 61120 KB
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no clearly defined way of determining in any tool I know of which processes share which maps without iterating through all the mappings and comparing addresses.

However, linux does offer reasonable estimate known as the *Proportional set size*. This is reported in /proc/[pid]>/maps.

This value is the  size of the mapping divided by the number of siblings/parent processes with the same mapping open.

So, with a program that has a 1MiB mapping open, plus a 1MiB shared with 4 other processes, the proportional set size is 1MiB + (1Mib / 4) or 1.250 MiB. The RSS in this case would be 2MiB.

There is a patch for htop floating around which will use the PSS to calculate a 'good estimate' of actual memory in use.